# How create new group when I get add-in in outlook by manifest?

Tags: xml, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have some trouble with understanding, how to create a new group in outlook when I make an add-in. (need make by code because after I add the add-in I load some info and configure the group based on this info)

I work with tutorial [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial)

here I add the add-in in the list menu, but how to change my manifest to create/add a new group [placing the group in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXlO.png).

I can create just this variant [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anIhg.png)

I' working just with manifest in visual studio code and try to change manifest and look at changes

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
<Requirements>
  <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
  </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
<Hosts>
  <Host xsi:type="MailHost"> <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/host-->
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>          

    <!-- Message Compose -->
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface"> <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint-->
      <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">  <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/desktopformfactor-->
        <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
          <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
          <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
            <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
            <Supertip>
              <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
              <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
              <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
            </Action>
          </Control>
          <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertDefaultGist">
            <Label resid="FunctionButton.Label"/>
            <Supertip>
              <Title resid="FunctionButton.Title"/>
              <Description resid="FunctionButton.Tooltip"/>
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
              <FunctionName>insertDefaultGist</FunctionName>
            </Action>
          </Control>
        </Group>
      </OfficeTab>
    </ExtensionPoint>

    </DesktopFormFactor>
  </Host>
</Hosts>

<Resources> <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/resources-->
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </bt:Urls>
  <bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Git the gist"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
    <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
    <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:LongStrings>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Displays a list of your gists and allows you to insert their contents into the current message."/>
    <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Inserts the content of the gist you mark as default into the current message."/>
  </bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
```

I tried to change the `ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface"` field to many of the variants but I took invalid schema or the same result. (`MessageComposeCommandSurface`, `AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface`, `AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface` and other ..)

Maybe I do something wrong or don't understand how to change manifests correctly to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXlO.png), which you shared.
Groups section is meant for [O365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-group-in-outlook-04d0c9cf-6864-423c-a380-4fa858f27102#ID0EACAAA=Web) and add-ins are not supported in this surface.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I guessed but wanted to know for sure.